# How to change the color of two divs for a matching game?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, colors

I am working on an assignment where you create a Memory game with a 4x4 grid of divs to serve as cards. The end goal is a user selects two cards. If they are a match then remove them from the game (Change the colors to white so the card appears gone) and if they are not a match, turn them back into black. I am using console.logs as placeholders just to show that the functions run properly, but I am stuck on how to change the colors. Additionally, the original colors of the cards have to remain showing for two seconds before changing to white or black. I know that this requires the use of setInterval, but my main concern is changing the colors of the cards and having them change to the proper colors depending on if it is a match. This is what I have so far:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-cell');
var i;
var picks = [];

//Event Listeners to respond to a click on the squares.
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
 elements[i].addEventListener('click', showColor);
}


function showColor(){
 this.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('data-color');
 picks.push(this.getAttribute('data-color'));
 console.log(picks);
 if(picks.length === 2){
  checkMatch();
  picks = [];
 }
}

function checkMatch(){
 if(picks[0] === picks[1]){
  console.log("Match");
 }else{
  console.log("Not a match");
 }
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 106.25px);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.grid-cell {
  height: 106.25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Memory</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

 <div class="game-container">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="red">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="blue">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="pink">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="orange">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="purple">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="green">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="yellow">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="grey">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="orange">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="red">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="green">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="pink">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="blue">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="grey">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="purple">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell" data-color="yellow">
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
 
 
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your code a little moved things around mostly and added a setTimeout so the user can see the color before it gets black or white, also added the event.target to the picks array so you know what elements to work with:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-cell');
var picks = [];

//Event Listeners to respond to a click on the squares.
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', showColor);
}


function showColor(event){
    this.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('data-color');
    picks.push({
      color: this.getAttribute('data-color'),
      target: event.target
    });
    if(picks.length === 2){
        checkMatch();
    }
}

function checkMatch(){
  if(picks[0].color === picks[1].color){
    console.log("Match");
    setTimeout(function(){
      picks.forEach(function(element){
        element.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        picks = [];
      })  
    },500);

  }else{
    console.log("Not a match");
    setTimeout(function(){
      picks.forEach(function(element){
        element.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      });
      picks = [];
    },500);
  }      
}
```

It can be refactor a little and improve some functions but you'll get the general idea.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just had to change the "match" option so it turns white, and I made the timer longer, but otherwise this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Ops, my bad I missed that one. I updated the answer. Glad to be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, it sets the timeouts right, but keep in mind that you have to disable the white squares. Also fix the issue where the same square is clicked twice.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-cell');
var i;
var picksColor = [];
var picks = [];

//Event Listeners to respond to a click on the squares.
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', showColor);
}


function showColor() {
  console.log(this);
  this.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('data-color');
  picksColor.push(this.getAttribute('data-color'));
  picks.push(this);
  console.log(picks);
  if (picks.length === 2) {
    checkMatch();
  }
}

function checkMatch() {
  if (picksColor[0] === picksColor[1]) {
    console.log("Match");
    setTimeout(function () {
      picks[0].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      picks[1].style.backgroundColor = 'white';

    }, 500);
  } else {
    console.log("Not a match");
    setTimeout(function () {
      picks[0].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      picks[1].style.backgroundColor = 'black';

    }, 500);
  }
  setTimeout(function () {
    picks = [];
    picksColor = [];
  }, 600);
}
```